# Filtering object array with ramda.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have an array of objects. I want to filter it to get objects, which any property contains the mathing string.

If my array is

```
 var data = [
 {"name: "John",
 "surname": "Smith"},
 {"name": "Peter",
 "surname: "Smithie"}]
```

I and filter with the string "Smi", it should return both items. If string is "John", only the first one.

This is my code:

```
var filtered = R.filter(R.where({ x: R.contains("Smi")}))(data);
```

I get error though:

```
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Could someone help me out with my Ramda function? Must the something small I'm missing, I guess. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem with this approach is that in `where({x: contains('Smi')})`, the `x` has no meaning.  Ramda does not include a notion of "for any key" like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
R.filter(R.pipe(R.values, R.any(R.contains('Smi'))))(data)
```

This is taking advantage of an undocumented feature of [`contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains), though, which is meant to work on lists, not strings. But it **[does work](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?code=%20const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20%22surname%22%3A%20%22Smith%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Joanie%22%2C%20%22surname%22%3A%20%22Jones%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Peter%22%2C%20%22surname%22%3A%20%22Smithie%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Smitty%22%2C%20%22surname%22%3A%20%22Jonsforth%22%7D%0A%20%5D%3B%0A%0AR.filter%28R.pipe%28R.values%2C%20R.any%28R.contains%28%27Smi%27%29%29%29%29%28data%29)**.

Answer (score 1):

I can not answer in Ramda but if you would like to implement the same functionality in JS you might easily do as follows;

```js
var   data = [{"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, {"name": "Peter", "surname": "Smirnof"}],
getObjects = (d,f) => d.filter(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].includes(f)));
console.log(getObjects(data,"Smi"));
console.log(getObjects(data,"Jo"));
```

Comment: Like the Rambda-less solution, which is not significantly bigger.